# Junit Mocking for dependent classes

Tags: java, junit

I am writing Junit for classes such as below

```
public class Class1 extends anotherClass{
   public final Class2 class2;
   public Class1 (Class2 class2) {
   this.class2 = class2;
   }
   @Override
   public String populate() {
      AnotherAbstractClass test1 = new AnotherAbstractClass();
      return class2.function(AnotherAbstractClass test1);
   }
}

public class Class2 extends anotherClass {
   public final Class3 class3;
   public Class1 (Class3 class3) {
   this.class33 = class3;
   }

   @Override
   public String populate() {
      AnotherAbstractClass test1 = new AnotherAbstractClass();
      return class2.function(AnotherAbstractClass test1);
   }

   public String function(AnotherAbstractClass test1) {
   return value;
   }
}
```

I am looking to mock AnotherAbstractClass in Class1 and pass it as a reference to class2 but the function is not executing. What is the right way to do it? The thing I tried,

```
@Mock
public AnotherAbstractClass anotherAbstractClass;
@Mock
public Class2 class2;

when(anotherAbstractClass.getFactory()).thenReturn(nullFactory)

String result = class2.function(anotherAbstractClass) //This is always throwing an exception)
```

Comment: can you provide a stacktrace?